# Associative law of scalar multiplication of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

If a,b are two real numbers and v is a vector, prove that: a*(b*v) = (a*b)*v.
I am trying to prove this equality by not using the fact that a vector can be represented by coordinates, but just by comparing the intensity, collinearity and direction of the two sides of the equality. Can anyone give me some help.

Answer (score 1):

according to wiki, this is one of the axioms for vector spaces (and thus cannot be proven for any vector space since you already know it):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition

if you want to *show* that $R^{n}$ with the component-wise multiplication is a vector space, you *need* to do it component-wise, since this would be your definition for this operation.

Comment: Is it possible to at least prove it for RxR ?